# bibliography entry missing

Tags: bibtex, errors

I have got a problem with BibTeX: For exhibition catalogues I have used the `misc` entrytype in Jabref and for sorting I have added a key = `{Ausst.Kat. place}`. This works fine. Only one entry always misses in my bibliography and it is always another one! Instead there appear only three letters in parentheses like for example `[Kan]` instead of `[Ausst.Kat. Kanazawa 2004]`.

After compiling I get an error message:

```
the literal stack isn't empty for Kanazawa2004 while executing --- line 2227 of file natdin.bst
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, in your case also including a minimal bibliography that shows the problem..

Comment: I have tried to create a MWE a few weeks ago. On my computer I could reproduce the problem, but when I sent the MWE to a friend, it worked fine. If I include single bibliography entries in my document, it works. But if I use the \nocite{*} the proble occurs. And, as I mentioned, anytime I restart LaTeX, there is another entry missing.

Comment: How do you compile your latex document? How did your friend compile the document? Did the MWE you've created not work on your machine but on the machine of your friend?

Comment: I use Miktex/Texniccenter and Jabref for the bibliography. I compile in the order Latex-Latex-Bibtex-Latex. In between I always get a warning, that the .bbl file has been changed outside the Texniccenter and the program asks if it should load it again.
And yes, the MWE I created did not work on my machine but on the one of my friend. I don't know how he compiles, but I think, I have got a problem with my Miktex or Texniccenter. For the next document I will use an updated version and try again. But for finishing my phd-thesis I don't want to make any experiments.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge)

Comment: Without a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), it's difficult to assess the problem. Closing as TL. You can edit the question and add detail, and it will automatically be flagged for re-opening at that time.